# Simple accordion with jquery

Tags: jquery

I building simple accordion with jquery. I try with jquery .next() method but no luck, nothing happens on click. Should I go with another jquery method or I'm on right way, Have any idea? 
Here is my html:

```
        <article class="TimBox">
          <img src="/images/Tim01.jpg">
          <div class="TimBoxTekst">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <h3>Subtitle 1</h3>
            <div class="LinkBox">
              <a href="#">more<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="TimBoxBio">Hidden text 1</div>
        </article>

        <article class="TimBox">
          <img src="/images/Tim01.jpg">
          <div class="TimBoxTekst">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
            <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
            <div class="LinkBox">
              <a href="#">more<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="TimBoxBio">Hidden text 2</div>
        </article>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".TimBox .LinkBox").click(function() {
        if($(this).next(".TimBoxBio").is(":visible")){
            $(this).next(".TimBoxBio").slideUp();
        return false;
        } else {
            $(".TimBox .TimBoxBio").slideUp();
            $(this).next(".TimBoxBio").slideToggle();
        return false;
        }       
    });
});
```

And here is css:

```
.TimBox .TimBoxBio{
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.next() is used to get the immediately following sibling. In your case, .TimBoxBio is not the next element relative to .LinkBox.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".TimBox .LinkBox").click(function() {
        var $bio = $(this).closest('.TimBox').find('.TimBoxBio');

        if($bio.is(":visible")){
            $bio.slideUp();
            return false;
        } else {
            $(".TimBox .TimBoxBio").slideUp();
            $bio.slideToggle();
            return false;
        }       
    });
});
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dou457gk/